# Geowebcache does not displaying map tiles in EPSG:900913 from a remote WMS server

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, wms, epsg, geowebcache

I connect  Geowebcache to a remote WMS service  through their Getcapability request by adding the url in geowebcache-servlet.xml document. Geowebcache demo page  displays the list of wms layers from the remote wms server.  When I click on the png link for the EPSG:900913 format ,  to display the map,  only displays the image place holders instead of map tiles. This displays map for the png link for EPSG:4326 formaT.  When I issue a Getmap request to the remote wms service directly from my browser, for EPSG:4326   works well but for EPSG:900913 it shows error “SRS Code 'EPSG:900913' is not supported (not found in SRS xml settings)”. When I check [their Getcapability document](http://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/Spatial/SDM.wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities)   I could not find EPSG:900913 in the SRS list, but EPSG:4326 is available.  Since I want display the map in google map api v2 , think i need EPSG900913 format to get this work.  I think geowebcache generate an automatic re-projection in EPSG:900913 format for googlemap api. This link  is not working for me, I think that could be the reason this is not displying in google map api.
could someone tell me a solution for this ? why the reprojection not working ?

Here is the [link for  EPSG:4326 format](http://ukypssgis.ca.uky.edu:8081/geowebcache/demo/SurveyAreaPoly?gridSet=EPSG:4326&format=image/png) , this will start disply at a scale 1:272K range 10th zoom

This is the  [link for  EPSG:900913](http://ukypssgis.ca.uky.edu:8081/geowebcache/demo/SurveyAreaPoly?gridSet=EPSG:900913&format=image/png) format which is not working for me.

This is the [link for the Geowebcache demo](http://ukypssgis.ca.uky.edu:8081/geowebcache/demo) page

I think there is a way to define independent layers and projections in geowebcache.xml document. Not sure how to do this to suit for my situation ?

Comment: EPSG:900913 has been deprecated in favour of EPSG:3857. They both represent the same projection, just the code has changed.

Answer (score 2):

GWC doesn't do reprojection, so you need to
download GeoServer 2.1 and set up your remote WMS as a cascading WMS, GeoServer will then reproject your remote WMS from 4326 to what ever projection you need. Then use the built in GWC to serve out tiles from the cascaded layer.

This blog post http://geo-solutions.blogspot.com/2010/10/wms-cascading-in-latest-geoserver.html describes how to set up your remote WMS. After that it behaves exactly as if you have a local layer.

Comment: iant, Thank you very much for the information. I am planning to update with the new version. I think this will be great solution for the issue. Other issue I am looking for is to style the WMS layer, which i found not supporting by geoserver now. I found some discussion [here](http://www.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2009-December/063760.html)  SLD is refered as url. Please let me know if this method will work with Geoserver ?